# Unable to get the dashboard of IBM websphere MQ in Azure Kubernetes

Tags: ibm-mq, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

We are trying to spin up a Stateful MQ manager with Azure File System as persistent storage mounted for data in an Azure Kubernetes cluster. Here is the [link](https://github.com/IBM/charts/tree/master/stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev) which we followed. We exposed the service type as LoadBalancer as shown in below command.

```
helm install stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev --version 3.0.1 --set service.type=LoadBalancer,security.initVolumeAsRoot=true,license=accept
```

By default, it takes default storage class as Azure disk. Here I want to use the Azure File System as Persistence storage.so, How should I pass my Azure file System name? and the other thing is, we can able to run the pod successfully without any restarts, but unable to access the web interface of it. so, we don't know where might be the exact issue raises while accessing the service?

Comment: I reattached my link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github repo you've linked specifically mentions `dataPVC.storageClassName` under [configuration](https://github.com/IBM/charts/tree/master/stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev#configuration). This is used to define storage class, if you dont have a storage class for Azure Files (i think it doesnt exist by default), you'd need to create it and then reference it, so it would use that class.

How to set it up: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv)

Comment: yeah, I have created a cluster role, role binding, and Storage class. I gave the command as follows `helm install stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev --version 3.0.1 --set dataPVC.storageClassName=azurefile,service.type=LoadBalancer,security.initVolumeAsRoot=true,license=accept`. Now pod gets restarted and generating the logs as 
    Error: Unable to change ownership of /mnt/mqm/data 2019-05-24T15:22:07.547Z chown /mnt/mqm/data: operation not permitted.

Comment: yeah, not enough permissions, that's probably because of security restrictions imposed by the chart

Comment: Can we change the security restrictions in the chart?

Comment: yeah, you can, i'm not sure the app will work, but thats a completely different question

Comment: In the Configuration section, any parameter might be useful to change the chart security restrictions?

Comment: just read the doc, one of the security something might do the trick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193905/discussion-between-gayathrib-and-4c74356b41).